# La differencia entre el pretérito anterior y el pretérito pluscuamperfecto

Tags: significado, historia, tiempos-verbales

El [artículo de wikipedia](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pret%C3%A9rito_anterior) sobre el pretérito anterior afirma que: "El pretérito anterior ha caído en desuso en español, y ha sido reemplazado en todos los registros salvo el culto por otra forma verbal como el pretérito pluscuamperfecto, el pretérito perfecto simple o indefinido, o incluso el infinitivo." Un ejemplo de uso del mismo artículo:

> Cuando hubo terminado de hablar, se fue.

A mis ojos anglosajones, no veo ninguna diferencia entre este y

> Cuando había terminado de hablar, se fue.

ambos se traduciría:

> When he had finished speaking, he went.

Es verdad que casi nunca se ve/oye esta forma en el español de hoy en día, pero siguen enseñándola en las escuelas (en Barcelona, por lo menos) para esas pruebas de gramática que les dan tanta alegría a los niños, así que me interesaría saber si hay una diferencia sutil.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probablemente el pretérito anterior ha caído en desuso precisamente por su poca diferencia con el pluscuamperfecto. La diferencia puede ser difícil de explicar a un no nativo, especialmente a un anglosajón porque el verbo auxiliar "haber" se traduce como "had" en los dos casos...

El pluscuamperfecto expresa un pasado anterior a otro pasado, mientras que el pret. anterior expresa un pasado **inmediatamente anterior** a otro pasado. Esa inmediatez es una marca muy sutil, tal vez incluso subjetiva, y es posiblemente la única diferencia entre ambos.

Para mí,

> Cuando hubo terminado de hablar, se fue.

Expresa

> **En cuanto** hubo terminado de hablar, se fue. (inmediatez)

Mientras que

> Cuando había terminado de hablar, se fue.

no tiene esta connotación. Bien podría ser, "había terminado de hablar, recogió sus cosas y se fue". No cabe cambiar ese *"Cuando"* por *"En cuanto"*, y por lo tanto no tiene esa marca de **inmediatez** (para mí, "En cuanto *había* terminado" suena mal, y favorecería "En cuanto *hubo* terminado" de forma incosciente).

Por ejemplo, entre estas dos:

1. Cuando hubo terminado, me llamó
2. Cuando había terminado, me llamó

Con la segunda, varias cosas podían haber pasado desde que "terminó" hasta que me llamó. Podría reescribir la frase como

> Cuando **ya** había terminado, me llamó / Me llamó cuando **ya** había terminado

No existe la connotación de inmediatez entre las dos acciones que hay en "cuando hubo terminado".

Pero, de nuevo, esta connotación es muy sutil. Si estuviese más marcada no habría una razón para que el pretérito anterior caiga en desuso frente a otros tiempos verbales.

Comment: Otra razón por la que quizás el pretérito anterior no es usado es porque puedes sustituir _Cuando hubo terminado, me llamó_ por _En cuanto terminó, me llamó_ denotando la misma inmediatez.

Answer (score 0):

**Las formas imperfectas son descriptivas, complementan la acción pero no datan.** Sería correcto decir:

> apenas había terminado se fué...

porque expresa la descripción subjetiva.

También es correcto :

> En cuanto hubo terminado se fue... (Explica cuándo se fue) .

Y si decimos terminó y se fue enseguida... asertamos que ocurrió y en qué espacio de tiempo, luego también cumplimos la ley sintáctica que exige que las formas indefinidas vayan datadas.

Decir :

> Cuando había terminado de hablar se fue...

es incorrecto desde el punto de vista temporal porque los imperfectos no están acabados... y para explicar que se marchó callado pero sin terminar de explicarse, tendría que recurrir, como he dicho antes, a descripciones no a dataciones que el imperfecto/pluscuamperfecto no necesita porque tienen que acompañar al indefinido/anterior.

El pretérito anterior. Al ser una forma perfecta anterior a la simple que necesita la datación (por no llevar  auxiliar entre otras razones).. para ser perfecta.

**Ya connota en sí mismo un tiempo real... aunque tal vez no cronológicamente necesario... si hubo explicado o no lo que dijo, no quedó muy claro...**

(Se había explicado,había intentado explicarse claramente,  pero no le queda constancia al que comunica de que lo consiguiera... No quedó muy claro si había explicado o no lo que dijo.... / el matiz enfático en la descripción de la segunda forma se corresponde, consecuentemente, con lo que en términos castellanos se explica con el refrán (El burro delante para que no se espante)

No vaya a ser que nuestro interlocutor no perciba nuestra opinión... **No es incorrecto llevar el burro delante...** pero no es lo mismo llevarlo de la cuerda ... que darle fuste "pa" que ande. Cada tiempo verbal precisa su referente temporal. Que es, en el argumento expositivo y en la descripción... sumamente importante... Tanto como el referente gramatical y semántico en la sintaxis. (Puedo estar seguro, con un riesgo mínimo, de que mi burro no cocea... pero el ajeno... es mas prudente... llevarlo de la cuerda)

Comment: A esta contribución no le vendría mal repasar el formato, empezando por hacer la entrada más legible dividiendo el contenido en párrafos. Aparte, no uses mayúsculas cuando puedes usar otros elementos de estilo, como itálica o negrita. Gracias.